# Using .setVisible() outside the constructor breaks my GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, multiple-instances

I am just now learning the basics of java GUI. I have this weird situation that I can't really explain.

I have a GUI class, where I build a simple JFrame. If I use `.setVisible(true)` **within the constructor** everything works fine, if I use it **outside**, *nothing loads* (the window is visible, but the buttons and what not aren't).

Why is this happening ?

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {


    private JTextField humanYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField dogYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JButton convert_Button = new JButton("Convert");
    private JLabel greeting = new JLabel ("Dog years to Human years!");

    public GUI () {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JPanel content = new JPanel();


        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(this.greeting);
        content.add(new JLabel("Dog Years: "));
        content.add(this.dogYears_TextField);
        content.add(this.convert_Button);
        content.add(new JLabel("Human Years: "));
        content.add(this.humanYears_TextField);

        window.setContentPane(content);
        pack(); // aplica contentPane-ul
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        window.setTitle("Dog Year Converter");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true); // IF IT'S HERE IT WORKS
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GUI dogYears = new GUI();
    //dogYears.setVisible(true); // IF IT'S HERE
                                 //NOTHING EXCEPT THE WINDOW LOADS
}
```

**Why is this happening ?**

In this example it doesn't matter, but what if I want to make a window visible only if I click a button or something ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You create 2 instances of `JFrame`  the first from extending `JFrame` on the class and the second from `JFrame window=..`. You than go on to call `setVisible(..)` on the `window` and in your main you attempt to call `setVisible(...)` on your `dogYears`.

**Solution**

You should only create one `JFrame` per Swing GUI. Get rid of the `extends JFrame` (and the code that goes with it), as its not good practice to extend `JFrame` in Swing. Thus of course you wont be able to call `setVisible(true)` in your constructor which is fine either call it after creating the GUI in the constructor or make a  method like `setVisible` in GUI class which will be a wrapper for your `JFrame`s `setVisble(boolean b)` method.

**Other suggestions**

- Always create your Swing components on the `Event Dispatch Thread` which you should do in via `SwingUtilitites.invokeLater(Runnable r)` block. Have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).
- Remember to call pack before setting `JFrame` visible and after adding components.
- `setLocationRelativeTo(..)` should come after `pack()`.
- Better to use `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` unless using Timers.
- Also no need for `setContentPane` simply call `add(..)` on `JFrame` instance.

Here is your code with above mentioned fixes:

[image]

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GUI {

    private JTextField humanYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField dogYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JButton convert_Button = new JButton("Convert");
    private JLabel greeting = new JLabel("Dog years to Human years!");
    private JFrame window = new JFrame();
    private JPanel content = new JPanel();

    public GUI() {
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(this.greeting);
        content.add(new JLabel("Dog Years: "));
        content.add(this.dogYears_TextField);
        content.add(this.convert_Button);
        content.add(new JLabel("Human Years: "));
        content.add(this.humanYears_TextField);

        window.add(content);

        window.setTitle("Dog Year Converter");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //window.setVisible(true); //works here now
    }

    //our wrapper method so we can change visibility of our frame from outside the class
    void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        window.setVisible(visible);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create Swing components on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GUI dogYears = new GUI();
                dogYears.setVisible(true);//works here too
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, all were initially typed within minutes of each other +1 for expanding :-)

Comment: Yep, ditto on what @kleo just said. 1+

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I just found this great answer and I've got one question, you said "create components on the EDT", so do I have to do all the work in Runnable or only for example calling the method setVisible(true)?

Answer (score 5):

You've got two `JFrame`s, the GUI class itself and the internal variable "window". Use only one.

Make sure that GUI does not extend `JFrame` (there's no need for this), and give the class a public void `setVisible(boolean)` method that sets the window to visible.

```
public class GUI {


    private JTextField humanYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField dogYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JButton convert_Button = new JButton("Convert");
    private JLabel greeting = new JLabel ("Dog years to Human years!");
    private JFrame window = new JFrame();

    public GUI () {

        JPanel content = new JPanel();


        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(this.greeting);
        content.add(new JLabel("Dog Years: "));
        content.add(this.dogYears_TextField);
        content.add(this.convert_Button);
        content.add(new JLabel("Human Years: "));
        content.add(this.humanYears_TextField);

        window.setContentPane(content);
        pack(); // aplica contentPane-ul
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        window.setTitle("Dog Year Converter");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // window.setVisible(true); // IF IT'S HERE IT WORKS
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        window.setVisible(visible);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Oh HFOE never saw this answer when doing mine. great minds think alike :P.

Comment: @Kalec: you are indeed correct that you will need a `pack()` method if this is not going to be called in the GUI class's constructor itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels your `setVisible(boolean visible)` would not compile as your `JFrame` - `window` is not declared within scope. Edited your code to reflect correct changes (move `JFrame` declaration to global)

Answer (score 4):

You have two different instances :-)

in your constructor:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setVisible(true); // IF IT'S HERE IT WORKS
```

in your main:

```
GUI dogYears = new GUI();
dogYears.setVisible(true); 
// dogYears != local var window in constructor
```

Which might get me starting on *not* extending classes, but using them.

Comment: It got *me* started on that. 1+

Comment: So then if I wanted to `setVisible`  in, let's say `main`. I'd have to make a function `getWindow` ? Set *that* to visible ? Or a wrapper method ?

Comment: Yes that may work work, but why is GUI extending JFrame if you do not use it as a JFrame, also see the EventDispatch posts and using SwingUtilitites.invokeLater(Runnable r)

Comment: lol +1 never saw all these posts when I started doing mine. +1 this is the problem

Answer (score 2):

Your class `GUI` extends from a `JFrame`, but in the constructor, you are initializing another JFrame, which results in having **two different** `JFrame`**s**.

Try this:

```
public class GUI {

    private JTextField humanYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JTextField dogYears_TextField = new JTextField(3);
    private JButton convert_Button = new JButton("Convert");
    private JLabel greeting = new JLabel ("Dog years to Human years!");

    public GUI () {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        content.add(this.greeting);
        content.add(new JLabel("Dog Years: "));
        content.add(this.dogYears_TextField);
        content.add(this.convert_Button);
        content.add(new JLabel("Human Years: "));
        content.add(this.humanYears_TextField);

        window.setContentPane(content);
        pack(); // aplica contentPane-ul
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        window.setTitle("Dog Year Converter");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    // main

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating an instance of JFrame in constructor of GUI which also extends JFRame.
Now you are creating different components and added them on 'window' object.
As you know a frame is set as visible= false and undecorated=false.
So to set a particular JFrame instance you need to call setVisible() method on that instance.

Here you are just creating an instance of GUI and didn't added any component on it.
write a statement in constructor as following rather than ***"window.setContentPane(content);"***:

setContentPane(content);

and then call setVisible() method on your instance of GUI class i.e d**ogYears.setVisible(true);**!!